# Display Monthly Attendance Report With Dynamic Dates in MySql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
STUDENTNAME   | ROLLNO | CLASS | 2013-06-01 | 2013-06-02 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-04 | 2013-06-05 | 2013-06-06 | 2013-06-07 | 2013-06-08 | 2013-06-09 | 2013-06-10 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Naren |      1 |    22 |          A |          A |          A |          A |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |
|       Srinu |      2 |    22 |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |
|        Blah |      3 |    22 |          A |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |          P |
```

I want the Attendance Report Like That

My Attendance Table is

```
Att_id   User_id    Attendance_date Present/Absent
1          1              2015-01-01    P
2          2              2015-01-01    L
3          1              2015-01-02    P
4          2              2015-01-02    P
5          1              2015-01-03    L
6          2              2015-01-03    L
```

i have one Stored Procedure

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN ca.date = ''',
      date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      ''' THEN coalesce(p.present, '''') END) AS `',
      date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM calendar
where date>='2013-06-01'
  and date <= '2013-06-05';

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT ca.user_id,
               ', @sql, ' 
            from
            (
              select c.date, a.user_id
              from calendar c
              cross join attendance a
            ) ca
            left join attendance  p
              on ca.user_id= p.user_id
              and ca.date = p.attendance_date
            where ca.date>=''2013-06-01''
              and ca.date <= ''2013-06-05''
          group by ca.user_id');
```

but here What is `@sql`. I didn't understood This Sql Store Procedure

Plz can you write in Mysql Stored Procedure

Comment: @sql is a user defined variable of mySQL in your query its not stored procedure. and what is your question? do you want an stored procedure for your above query?

Comment: Yeah i want The Mysql Stored Procedure For above query

Comment: is your query working fine.?

Comment: No not working i didnt how to pass user defined variable of mySQL in that query And im trying to get the report of Attendance Monthly

Comment: you can make your procedure parametrized as i have written it in general syntax in my update

Answer (score 0):

General Syntax

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE `moodle`.`procedureName`(IN id INT, IN NAME VARCHAR(20))

    BEGIN
          --    paste QUERY here;
                SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = NAME  AND user_id =id;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

this is a parametrized stored procedure where which contain two **`IN`** type parameter named as **id** whose **`datatype`** is **`int`** other is **`name`** whose **`datatype`** is **`varchar(20)`** which are passe as `user_name = NAME` and `user_name = NAME` in query in the stored procedure.

you can call stored procedure using following query

```
call procedureName(1,'test');
```

**`@sql`** is not an stored procedure it is user defined variable as **`var`** is in below case

```
SET @var='testing varible';
SELECT @var;
```

by running the query above you will get the value stored in the above variable

Comment: i will try the query in that way

Comment: i have added some descriptions for you

Comment: When im trying to excute the query it's shows the error at
  = CONCAT('SELECT ca.user_id,
               ', @sql, '  
            Here

Comment: actually your query has some extra ' quotations first of all check out your query by running it normally if it is running perfect then go for the procedure

Comment: you have not provided the structure of all the tables that you have used in query eg: calender so i can not help you anymore

Comment: this error is in your mySQL query not in procedure first of all check out your query remove extra ' (quotations) and , (commas) from your query i hope it will work.First of all check out your query by running it normally if it is running perfect then go for the procedure

Comment: My calendar tables have two columns ie id and date

Comment: so here im going to compare the dates of attendance and calendar and based on that im trying to get the output like month wise  as shown in the above figure

Comment: what is p.present? in 2nd query

Comment: that p.present is from attendnace table

Comment: some how i got the output we have add the SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; in query.Thank you so much for your help and response